# Declared the 2d array but never used in the nested loop to print. If I remove the 2d array declaration program is running without asking input

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main(){
    int rows;
    int columns;
    
    int k=1;
    printf("enter the number of rows: \n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("\nEnter the number of cloumns: \n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);
    int a[rows][columns];
    int i= 1;
    while(i<=rows){
        int j=1;
        while(j<=columns){
            // a[rows][columns] =k;
            printf("%d\t",k);
            k++;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Declared 2d array but never used in while loop to print. When I try to remove the array declaration loop is running infinite times without taking the input. Need to know what is the role of 2d array here.

Comment: `int i= 1; while(i<=rows)` should be `int i= 0; while(i<rows)` and similarly for `columns`. In C an array in indexed from `[0]` to `[dimension-1]`. For that reason too, `// a[rows][columns] =k;` would be indexing out of range, with *undefined behaviour* resulting. You would need `a[i][j] =k;`

Comment: // a[rows][columns] =k; without this value assignment how program is running and printing the results.

Comment: That array is never being used (except incorrectly written to). It is `k` that is printed.

Comment: your program looks fine, I don't see any infinite loop after testing the code. What are the inputs you using?

Comment: @Sudipto the undefined behaviour (writing with out-of-range array indexes) is probably corrupting the loop control variables. It is not fine.

Comment: I don't think it can corrupt the behaviour of the loop. The array is just declared never used. I also tested the code locally as he described.

Comment: @Sudipto.. program is working fine when we leave the declared array. But when we comment it the program is looping infinite times without taking inputs of rows and columns.

Comment: I don't know why I don't see that kind of behavior. I used the following code [here](https://controlc.com/d9196250)

Comment: Thanks @Sudipto now the code is behaving as expected there is no point of declaring 2d array. No garbage values are generated.

Comment: @Weather Vane: I have used the 2d array to assign the value starting with a[1][1] not with a[0][0]. Still it printed the result as expected